# Creating a gcloud command for Dataflow Pipeline job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, gcloud

We recently created a Dataflow Job and Pipeline within the Google Cloud Console.
For record-keeping purposes, I want to record the `gcloud` equivalent commands for both the job and pipeline.
I managed to determine the `gcloud` equivalent command for the Dataflow Job, but I am unable to figure out how to create the `gcloud` equivalent for the Dataflow Pipeline.

Sample Dataflow Job Gcloud command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run sample_dataflow_job --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-east1/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery --region us-east1 --num-workers 2 --staging-location gs://dataflow_single_region_us/writingdirectory --subnetwork https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/sample-project/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/project_network --disable-public-ips --parameters connectionURL=jdbc:mysql://psql.gcp.sample.net:6033/sample,driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver,query=select * from datab,outputTable=bigquerytable:sample.sample_DataFlow_1,driverJars=gs://dataflow_single_region_us/jdbc_driver,bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=gs://dataflow_single_region_us/bigqueryloading,username=johnsmith,password=Password1
```

Any ideas how I can get the `gcloud` command for the Dataflow Pipeline solution?

Comment: Could you clarify how you created this job and pipeline? Were you using templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dig a bit on cloud sdk documentation and found that the feature was released a couple of days ago, please check [Google Cloud CLI - Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_datapipelines) about `cloud datapipelines`. Still, it's in [beta](https://cloud.google.com/products#section-22). You can check [gcloud beta datapipelines](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/datapipelines) page for additional details.

As this feature is still in `beta` it may have limited support. It's not recommended to use this in production environments and it's only for testing at the moment. For now, I think we will have to wait until it's fully released.

Comment: Thank you so much.   I will consult the documentation and try the beta in the meantime